# How to pass new query params to URL in Vue and reload even if its the same page?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I have a website that has a search bar. When the user searches and hits enter, I need the page to reload with the new query params in the URL.

The problem is, if the user is already on that page, even though the query params are updating, the page does not reload. I have to physically hit refresh to see the new results.

I already know that I can pass in a key to `router-view` to fix this issue but I need an alternative as no where in my project is `router-view` even used.

What is another option to simply reload the page?

```
redirect({ lat, lng }) {
  router.push({ name: 'test-route', query: { lat, lng }})
}
```

Comment: did you try to set a watcher for route changes?

Comment: I just realized the parent component is TypeScript so I think I can do that, just have to figure out how

Comment: would `location.reload();` do the trick?

Comment: For some reason no, it reloads the page but not with the params even if I call `location.reload()` last

Comment: what I would is (assuming composition api), store search result in reactive or ref, then "watch(() => route.query, () => { //doSearch and update searchResults })

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
          this.$router.replace({
            ...this.$router.currentRoute,
            query: your new list of query parameters, can be an empty object
          });
```

Keep in mind that if the new query object has the same key/value pairs as the current one - VueRouter will not perform a navigation.

However, if there is not even a single `<router-view>` in your application - you won't be able to change routes because Vue does not know where to render the route.